# variable length struct in gnuc

Tags: c, linux, struct

Is it able to define a variable length struct in gnuc to represent a object as follow:

```
field1: fixed 4bytes;
field2: length of field3
field3: variable length
field4: length of field5
field5: variable length
field6: fixed 8bytes
field7: fixed 1byte
```

I know in gnuc we can use the zero-size array to implement a variable length struct, e.g.

```
typedef struct varStruct{
  int foo1;
  int foo2[0];
}varStruct;
```

But the above usage requires the variable length field placed at the tail of the struct.
What if they are in the middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a struct with more than one variable array or a variable array in the middle. Think about it, how would the compiler know where `field3` and `field4` start if the length `field2` is variable?

If `field1` contains the length of the next two fields, you could read the members of the struct manually. Example code (read it as pseudocode):

```
#define PADDING 8 /* or perhaps sizeof(void *) */

typedef struct {
   int32_t field_len;
   char data[0];
} main_str_t;

typedef struct {
   int64_t one;
   int8_t another;
} tail_str_t;

....

main_str_t *data = get_data();
int32_t len = data->field_len;
int32_t padded_len = ((field_len + PADDING - 1) / PADDING) * PADDING;
char *field2 = data->data;
char *field3 = field2 + padded_len;
tail_str_t *tail = field3 + padded_len;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, since the compiler (is responsible for and) will not be able to calculate offsets for `field4` and `field5`.

Comment: What if add the length of those variable length field into this struct? I have changed the struct.

Comment: More specifically, it is *absolutely trivial* to generate the operations to read the field lengths and use the appropriate offsets for the later fields. **But C has no facilities for doing so.**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do this with 3 structs and do a little address arithmetic at run-time:

```
struct1:
  field1: fixed 4bytes;
  field2: length of field3
  field3: variable length

struct2:
  field4: length of field5
  field5: variable length

struct3:
  field6: fixed 8bytes
  field7: fixed 1byte
```