# Can a C compiler add padding before the first element in a structure?

Tags: c

Specifically, I was wondering if I could make something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char *s; /* still a cstr, with '0' bit at end */
    size_t len;
} str;
str *newstr(char *s) {/*...*/};
void freestr(str *s) {/*...*/};
```

and do things like this (treat it as a cstr with `stdlib/string` functions):

```
int main() {
    str *s = newstr("hello");
    printf("The first character of '%s' is '%c'", *s, (*s)[0]);
    freestr(s);
}
```

If not, it's not a big deal—and, of course, I'm not really concerned about wasting a byte.

Comment: Of course you won't be able to subcript your structure like that - you'll need C++ to do operator overloading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6661331/249230

Comment: That `printf()` call won't work — it expects a `char*` and a `char`, but you're effectively passing a `char**` and a `char*`.

Comment: You meant: `printf("The first character of '%s' is '%c'", *s, (*s)[0]);`, didn't you?

Comment: @alk: Uh oh, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that's a place where the standard explicitly forbids placing any padding. The address of the first member of a struct and the address of the struct must be the same.

Section 6.7.2.1 (15) in the n1570 draft of the C2011 standard states:

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.** There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7):

No. The C standard requires that there be no padding before the first element in the structure. But it is the only thing it guarantees. There may be (undocumentedly sized) padding between further fields.

From the [ISO C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): (6.7.2.13):

> 13 Within a structure object, the non-bit-ﬁeld members and the units in which bit-ﬁelds
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Answer (score 5):

No.

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p13) "There may be unnamed padding within a structure
>               object, but not at its beginning."

There may be padding after any structure member (including the last one) but there cannot be padding before the first structure member.