# Casting a struct to a pointer type that points to its first element

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct

While looking at:

[Can a C compiler add padding before the first element in a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210239/can-a-c-compiler-add-padding-before-the-first-element-in-a-structure)

I came up with the following code:
(Ignore the fact that memory isn't freed in this example.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *cstr;
    size_t len;
} str_t;

void setStr(str_t* dest, const char* src)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    dest->cstr = malloc(len + 1);
    dest->len = len;
    memcpy(dest->cstr, src, len + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    str_t str;
    setStr(&str, "woot!");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Amazingly, this actually works. This call:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

seems to be equivalent to this one:

```
printf("%s\n", str.cstr);
```

So one would think that the following is also possible:

```
char* plainstr = malloc(str.len + 1);
strcpy(plainstr, str);
```

But no go. In contrast to `printf`, `strcpy` is not variadic, so there's type checking. The compiler rightfully complains:

```
passing 'str_t' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'
```

But trying to tell the compiler "I really mean it" by casting it:

```
strcpy(plainstr, (const char*)str);
```

Won't work either:

```
operand of type 'str_t' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

Note that the following can't work:

```
strcpy(plainstr, (const char*)&str);
```

Since `str.cstr != &str`. For example, the output of this:

```
printf("%p %p\n", str.cstr, &str);
```

Is the following:

```
0xbdb010 0x7fff788f6ab8
```

And indeed, garbage data is being copied to `plainstr`.

So the questions are:

1. Why isn't it allowed to cast a struct to a pointer type?
2. How come that `printf` deals with this correctly if casting isn't allowed?

Comment: That can't work, since `str.cstr != &str`.

Comment: ... but that's all so ugly! :-( *shiver*

Comment: @alk Sorry for that! Blame it on K&R. (Well, just on K, nowadays. :-( )

Comment: `str.cstr` and `&str` are not equal. Of course the code can be compiled, but the resulting pointer doesn't point to the string, so the wrong data is being copied. I updated the question with code that shows this.

Comment: `str.cstr` is a pointer value that holds an address of a string on the heap. `&str` is an address of a `struct` on the stack, but it is also the address of the pointer value `cstr` that holds the address on the heap. Try comparing `&str.cstr` versus `&str`.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Those are equal, but they're not what we want, since they're both `!= str.cstr`, which is what points to our data. Turns out that what we want is actually `*(const char **)&str`, as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @alk It wan't a beauty contest :-P Simply wanted to explain behavior I found weird. I wouldn't actually use this code for anything real.

Comment: @NikosC. yeah, I was just pointing out the relationship between `str` and `str.cstr`. Of course, `&str` wouldn't be equal to the *value* of `str.cstr`, since that points to the heap and the struct is on the stack. Good solution though. This many years after C was created, pointers still confuse the hell out of people.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Call me masochistic, but it's one of the reasons I love C ;-)

Comment: @NikosC. You're seriously cool. All I heard so far about C pointers is that it's confusing, it's hard, it's ugly, etc. Nobody believed me they are one of the reasons C is **the perfect language** for serious native development. Really, C is well-designed, apart from a few minor inconsistencies in the Standard, it's really a good balance between efficiency and ease of use. It's abstract enough to be easy-to-use, but not more (than necessary). And I love it, seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't it allowed to cast a struct to a pointer type?

Because it makes no sense. How would you reinterpret a whole bunch of possibly unrelated information of distinct types as a concise memory address? However, in the previous question you asked, all of the people who answered, [cited the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210239/can-a-c-compiler-add-padding-before-the-first-element-in-a-structure/13210249#13210249), and one particular statement in the standard stated that

> The address of the structure is the address of its first element

So (as @Mat already pointed it out), you **can** indeed write

```
strcpy(destination, *(const char **)&str);
```

and that "will work" for the reasons I just enumerated.

> How come that printf deals with this correctly if casting isn't allowed?

Because in C, typecasting is often just for fooling the compiler (except when it isn't). By passing the structure, the structure will be copied, and your stack will be something like (I'm intentionally omitting any padding from the structure for the sake of simplicity):

```
> top of the stack: pointer to the format string
> address of the copied struct *and*  address of the copy of the char pointer
> address of the length of the string (size_t)
> every other stuff
```

So, now what `printf()` will do is:

- pop off the first value off the stack. It will be the format string.
- Now when it encounters the `%s` format specifier in the format string, it will pop off another char pointer - in reality, it's the pointer to the structure, and the pointer to the first element, which is the string to be printed.
- So it happily prints the string and returns.

Also, this is *still undefined behavior,* despite the fact that it works - if you don't specify a format string for `printf()` that actually corresponds to the types you pass in as its variadic arguments, that's not conformant and you can expect anything to happen.

Comment: `strcpy(destination, (const char *)&str);` does not work. By "work" I mean copying `str.cstr` to `destination`. Your explanation of how `printf` ends up with the correct address makes sense though.

Comment: @NikosC. Thanks! I also updated the answer - I think it should now really work like this.

Comment: Since the address of a struct's first element must be the same as the address of the struct, I can assume that `*(const char **)&str` is *not* UB, right?

Comment: Looks like Mat's answer was removed, but I liked the reference from the C99 standard. Too bad.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee Mat has removed it himself. But here you are a link to the section I cited.