# Why does & operator give different value for struct type

Tags: c, memory-address

Consider the following test program ([codepad execution](http://codepad.org/pdYxZ0Xw)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct camp {
    char b[8];
};


int main()
{
    struct camp c;
    strcpy(c.b, "Hello");
    c.b[5] = '\0';
    printf("c size: %d\nAddress (amp): %d :: %d\n", sizeof(c), &c, c);
    printf("Address of b: %d :: %d\n", &(c.b), c.b);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample output:

```
c size: 8
Address (amp): -1082463628 :: 1819043144
Address of b: -1082463628 :: -1082463628
```

Whereas the address given by `&(c.b)` and `c.b` (second call to printf) is same, the same for `struct camp c` (first call to printf) returns different address. Furthermore, `&c` being same as `&(c.b)` or `c.b`.

What exactly is happening?

Comment: `1819043144` --> `0x6C6C6548` --> `Hell`, first four characters of `Hello`

Comment: @Musa Because he used code that relied on undefined behavior, the program went to hell?

Comment: @Musa ...in little endian =P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a struct to a pointer type that points to its first element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210741/casting-a-struct-to-a-pointer-type-that-points-to-its-first-element)

Comment: Btw, use `%p` for printing your addresses and pointer values. *please*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Did not knew that, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `printf` is trying to do in the first case is to interpret `c` as an integer. `c` is *not* an integer, or even a value that can be converted to an integer (explicitly or implicitly), so the value written can be anything as you are invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one data member in the struct hence you are seeing the same address for `b` as well as for `c` the struct object.

Also array name gives the address of the first element of that array.Hence , `c.b` will give the same address as `&(c.b)` since the later one is address of whole array.

`&c` `&(c.b)` and `c.b` will be same in your case but you are printing the `c` using `%d` format specifier , so you are seeing an `undefined behaviour` , The last argument is not the address of `c` (so you are getting garbage value).